# How to fix image within a flexbox, ignoring containers height?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, height

Hi in my project I have just set up a card element with a div containing an image at the top and text below. My issue is that the div that contains the image when set to 100% height uses the height of the card not the height of the parent div. Does anyone know what the fix is?

css:

```
.Cards {
        position: absolute;
        width: 85%;
        height: 85%;
        background: white;
        box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-top: 20%;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 7px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: #7510f7;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;


        .image-iframeContainer {
            display: flex;
            width: 100%;
```

//removing this height value or setting it too 100% is what breaks it /doesn't work

```
            height: 50vh;
            background: #141c3a;
            overflow: hidden;

            img {
                width: auto;
                height: auto;
                max-width: 100%;
                max-height: 100%;
                object-fit: cover;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                margin: auto;
            }

            iframe {
                position: absolute;
                margin: 0;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                border: 0;
            }
        }
```

here's my sandbox so you can see:
https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-sunset-jqjst?file=/src/styles.scss

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of unnecessary css code there

```
    .App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.webAppStyles {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  // remove thise 2, they dont do nothing in this case
  //  position: relative;
  //  overflow-x: hidden;

  // remove this class, it does absolutley nothing in this case
  // .Stack {
  //    width: 100%;
  //    height: 100%;
  // }

  .Cards {

    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 50%;
    height: 80%;
    margin: 10% auto 0;

    // duplicate property, remove this too
    // background: white;
    
    box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    
    // this is override at h1 and p, doesnt make any sense to add it here, remove it
    // text-align: center;

    border-radius: 7px;

    // this doesnt do anything here remove it
    // overflow: hidden;

    background: #7510f7;
    
    .image-iframeContainer {
      // you dont need flex againg, it's only an image in this container, nothing to flex here
      // display: flex;

      // any div has width 100% unless you told it to be smaller or bigger
      // width: 100%;
      
      background: #141c3a;
      
      // there is your problem, but right now can be safely removed, the problem was all that css code added for nothing
      // height: 100%;
      
      // doesnt do anything here
      // overflow: hidden;

      img {
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        margin: auto;
      }

      iframe {
        position: absolute;
        margin: 0;
        top: 50px;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border: 0;
      }
    }

    h1 {
        margin-top: 0;
        // remove this, default is left
        // text-align: left;
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 2px;
        margin-left: 2px;
    }

    p {
        font-size: 0.8rem;
        // remove this, default is black
        // color: black;
        // remove this, default is left
        // text-align: left;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-left: 2px;
    }

    .carousel-root{
      flex:1;
    }

    .carousel {
      z-index: 0;
    }

    .carousel, .slider-wrapper, .slider {
      height: 100%;
    }

    .slide {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much will test out in a sec and see if it fixes my problem thank you! Then will respond as fixed

Comment: Hi again after looking through I'm not sure you understood what I wanted, the display flex property on image-iframeContainer div was used to add margin auto so landscape pictures would sit centre of the div, this is because on my project the images will vary and will be input through a JSON array. Thank you for helping declutter though there was a lot of unnecessary Css, if you work out how to get the div to fill the 100% of the carousel height please let me know though!

Comment: also, position relative is needed to centre the div correctly in my project

Comment: Just checking if you use the sandbox again you can see that your answer only appears to work but if you widen the aspect ratio of the display its clear it's just using 100% of the height of the image not 100% of the size of the carousel root

Answer (score 1):

[how to stop images within a flexbox container ignoring the heigth set by parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63957956/how-to-stop-images-within-a-flexbox-container-ignoring-the-heigth-set-by-parent)

question answered here flex-basis:0 is needed on the image container with flex-grow:1

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand what you are trying to achieve, and I am unable to comment under your post. But from the information given I figured you wanted the picture to fill the space above the text. I saw in your sandbox, the images had black bars on top and below, and I figured you wanted the picture to fill these.

So I removed the extra div you had wrapped around the div around the image, and I changed the styles of your card. I forked your sandbox and made the adjustments there, [check it out!](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-matsumoto-h7gov?file=/src/App.js) I hope this is what you were after..

### HTML

```
<Carousel>
 <div className="image-iframeContainer">
  <img>
```

### SCSS

```
.Cards {
    //position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    //height: 80%;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your input, if you look previously at my sandbox the cards where swipeable and positioned absolutely so they could be swiped, try it out! but anyway in your example the cards swiping is broken although the image does scale correctly lol, I want the containing div to fill 100% of the carousel I'm using this for background colour, in my final project pictures of varying aspect ratios and sizes will be used I don't want them cropped or stretched hense the bars, hope you understand now any ideas?