# how to stop images within a flexbox container ignoring the heigth set by parent?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, flexbox

For the past couple of days, I thought the issue I've been having was with the API that i was using but after stumbling upon this [article talking about flex:1 issues](https://medium.com/@gaurav5430/css-flex-positioning-gotchas-child-expands-to-more-than-the-width-allowed-by-the-parent-799c37428dd6) I've discovered it's not.
The article addresses the issue but not for images what's the fix?

**HTML**

```
<div className="App">
  <div className="box1">
    <img src={image} />
  </div>
  <div className="box2" />
  <div className="box3" />
</div>
```

**Scss**

```
.App {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  .box1{
    flex: 1;
    background: blue;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
img{
  margin: auto;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 300px;
  //try max height 100% breakesit
  //max-height: 100%
  object-fit: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
  }
  
  .box2{
    background: purple;
    height:200px; 
  }
  .box3{
    background: green;
    height: 250px;
  }
}
```

**[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-platform-rii0v?file=/src/styles.scss:0-515)**

I would the like the image to take up 100% of the parent divs height is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a reasonable fix not using a background image but playing further with flex box! here's my solution:

**HTML**

```
 <div className="App">
      <div className="box1">
        <img src={image} />
      </div>
      <div className="box2" />
      <div className="box3" />
    </div>
```

> It turns out as far as I can understand images have there own unique
> flex-basis property based on there actual size which is different from
> every other element and they use this as there default flex property
> which they grow or shrink from, so setting this value to
> 0(**flex-basis:0**) makes it behave the same way as a regular element.
> The only issue with this on its own is the height of the image will
> stay at 0px no matter the percentage set this can simply be fixed by
> adding the **flex-grow:1** property

**Sass**

```
.App {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  .box1{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 0;
    background: blue;
    overflow: hidden;

    img{
      width: auto;
      height: auto;
      max-width: 100%;
      max-height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      margin: auto;
    }
  }
  
  .box2{
    background: purple;
    height:200px; 
  }
  .box3{
    background: green;
    height: 250px;
  }
}
```

Here's a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-platform-rii0v?file=/src/styles.scss:0-549) demonstrating for you to play around with as this seems to be a largely unanswered question hope it helps some people who were struggling as much as I was!

Answer (score -1):

You can use your image as a background of the div

```
.box1{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

<div className="box1" style={{background: `url(${image})`}}>
```

Comment: will this severely stretch the image? I was hoping to display the full image with borders either top or bottom depending on the aspect ratio of the image that's injected?

Comment: you can adapt the type of background. Look this article: https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: this is a great one too: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background/

Comment: this seems very promising I'm trying it in the sandbox as we speak if it works as intended I'll definitely integrate it into my project!

Comment: Thank you for this comment @Steve Cruz. You can use a <span> to resolve this and make your site more accessible. https://www.davidmacd.com/blog/alternate-text-for-css-background-images.html

Comment: Maybe there is an Aria role that can help

Comment: Wow that is a great link Gabriel. I'll read it later.

Comment: @GabrielFerrari I'm strugging to css that gives me the desired function on th background nothing seems to be working

Comment: background-size: contain; seems to be ignored which is what i want really :/

Comment: could you share a visual example of what you need? I can try to help.

Comment: I want the image to scale to be 100% of the size of the div the has flex on it, whats the best way to show you? does my sandbox not help?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the sandbox. Let me take a look.

Comment: ok so if you look at my sandbox I want that image to fill the max height of the blue div, with no stretching or cropping. I hope that make sense lol?

Comment: The problem here is, you have an image that the height is bigger than the width, but your div is the opposite. So you don't have many options.

Comment: yeah I get that but that I don't want the image to fill 100% off the width, I'd like it to have borders as in contained? you're telling me there is no way to do this?

Comment: if you can't answer the question could you upvote it please to bring some attention to it?

Comment: please, share with us